# ¿Cómo resolver este problema interpretando este inner join?

Tags: join, inner

Estoy teniendo problemas interpretando un INNER JOIN.
Tengo dos tablas que son IDÉNTICAS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT c.* FROM tabla_C c JOIN tabla_D d ON c.ID = d.ID
```

Obtengo un resultado que es el esperado por mí.
Hasta acá todo perfecto.

Sin embargo, al ejecutar la siguiente instrucción:

```
SELECT c.* FROM tabla_C c JOIN tabla_D d ON c.X = d.X
```

Esperaba obtener el mismo resultado. Pero en su lugar obtuve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podría explicar el por qué de este resultado?

Comment: Yo veo que el resultado está perfecto y sale justo lo que me esperaba... Si lo piensas, tienes valores repetidos en la columna X, con lo cual es lógico que al hacer un join, te salgan repetidos ciertos ID. Piensa que un `join` es básicamente la multiplicación de una tabla por la otra, es decir, si tienes el valor `10` en los campos con ID 1 y 2, es obvio que te va a salir dos veces dichos campos, porque el 10 de cada campo es igual al 10 de otros dos campos... entonces tienes dos `10` por dos `10`, 4 campos con X = 10... que es justo el resultado que te da

Comment: ejecuta  SELECT c.* FROM tabla_C c JOIN tabla_D y veras que es el producto cartesiano(cada uno con todos)

Comment: @Francisco Eso es, producto cartesiano! No me salía el nombre :) Un `join` normal es literalmente la multiplicación de ambas tablas una por la otra. Luego los left, right, outer, inner... modifican la cantidad de resultados que se escogen, pero la base de un join siempre es la multiplicación de todas las filas :)

Comment: Luego aplicas el filtro o la condición y es lo que te va a salir

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Comment: A pesar de leer y releer tu razonamiento, lo comparo con mi resultado y sigo sin entenderlo. Si me aferro a tu lógica, debería obtener todos los resultados duplicados. Y no es lo que obtengo. Algunos se duplican y otros no. Básicamente está comparando valores que son idénticos.

Comment: El cardinal(numero de elementos resultantes) es la multiplicación,p.e en este caso 10 x10= 100 filas tendrá SELECT c.* FROM tabla_C c JOIN tabla_D pero el resultado es una combinación

Comment: Si es producto cartesiano; que no te los muestre exactamente en le orden que los esperas es otra cosa (porque nada garantiza que salgan en un orden dado a menos que uses ORDER BY)

Comment: @tuertense te salen repetidos porque las dos tablas son iguales

Comment: SELECT c.*,d.id as did FROM tabla_C c JOIN tabla_D d ON c.X = d.X y veras que no salen filas repetidas

Comment: Probé el SELECT c.*,d.id FROM tabla_C c JOIN tabla_D d ON c.X = d.X y me arroja el mismo resultado. La diferencia que que me agrega la columna ID de la tabla D.

Comment: @Francisco. Entiendo que me salgan repetidos porque tengo dos tablas iguales. Pero fijate que no salen TODOS repetidos. Solo se repiten algunos registros. Esta es la parte que me desorienta.

Comment: @Benito entiendo lo que decís. Pero según tu razonamiento, también debería repetirse, por ejemplo, el ID = 3. Y eso no pasa!!

Comment: No sabemos si tu cliente de la BD te está mostrando los primeros N registros y por eso no ves TODOS los 20. Pero no te enredes; los join funcionan tal cual te han explicado acá

Comment: @alfabravo no dudo que lo que explican es tal cual. Sigo esta página de hace años y despejo muchas dudas. Hay gente que sabe una barbaridad. Pero me pasa que no le encuentro la lógica al resultado de mi consulta. Y sigo sin encontrarla.

Comment: Piensa que estas filtrando por una columna X que tiene datos repetidos y las dos tablas son iguales, vale?. por ejemplo 3 solo esta una vez sale 1 vez (1x1=1). el 10 dos veces sale cuatro veces (2x2=4) piensa que detrás de todo esto esta el producto cartesiano de las dos tablas.Tienes que tener claro como se hace el producto cartesiano

Comment: @Francisco. Con tu último comentario, y releyendo los comentarios anteriores, ahora me queda mucho más claro. Gracias a ti y a todos por sus aportes. Hasta hoy no tenía idea del producto cartesiano. Y en lo que he buscado en internet no he encontrado información al respecto. Solo lees que los INNER JOIN combinan claves mediante condición, varios ejemplos, pero poco he visto sobre la forma de trabajo.

Comment: De nada, yo siempre lo  he pensado así y me da buen resultado porque es mas general

Answer (score 0):

El JOIN realiza la unión de las columnas de las 2 tablas, en el primer caso con la columna ID, los valores son únicos, en cambio, en la columna X tienes valores repetidos.
Por ejemplo con el valor 10, EL JOIN de LA TABLA C con la TABLA D será: tabla A (id 1, valor 10) con tabla D (id 1, valor 10) y tabla D (id 2, valor 10), y tabla A (id 2, valor 10) con tabla  D (id 1, valor 10) y tabla D (id 2, valor 10). Con lo que tendremos cuatro veces el número 10 porque al cruzarse da todos los valores posibles.

Comment: Y, por ejemplo, por qué no me repite el ID 3?

Comment: El ID 3, con valor X = 3 solo está una vez en la X (No hay otra fila que tenga un 3 en la X), por lo cual al multiplicar 1 x 1... obtienes 1. Son literalmente multiplicaciones, si tienes un campo repetido 2 veces, obtendrás 4 resultados, si solo está una vez, obtendrás 1, si se repite 3 veces obtendrás 9 (3 x 3). Por eso el 3 solo sale una vez, no estás *sumando* los campos, estás **multiplicando** los campos!

Comment: Si quieres un ejemplo en el que se vea mejor, añade un campo extra a cada tabla, por ejemplo en la primera añade el campo c1, en la segunda tabla el campo c2 y añade en cada fila un valor único (simplemente un número de 0 a N llegará). Al hacer el join verás como te sale literalmente la multiplicación de todas las posibles combinaciones. En tu caso como todos los campos son idénticos se complica ver lo que en realidad está pasando.